# Fail when one command fail in sub-command

Tags: bash, shell, find, exit

I want to execute a command in a list of directories : `gradle --build-cache`. Additionnly the directory need to start with the string 'Project" and not ending with "Test". I succeed doing that with this command:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -name "Project*" ! -name "*Test*" -exec sh -c "cd '{}' && pwd && gradle --build-cache" \;`

But my problem is that the gradle command can fail. If I launch the command alone it returns 'exit 1' but if one of the directory command failed it do not return the fail and the script continue. At the end, the loop return success `exit 0`...

**How can I stop the loop execution when the gradle command failed and return for the general command an `exit 1` ?**

Thanks :)

Comment: When you say "loop", you mean the `find` process, right? You want `find` to abort when any of the commands started by `-exec` fails? Or just for `find` to return an error in that case?

Comment: Yeah, the loop I talk about, it's the find. I want that if `gradle --build-cache` return failed, I want tje whole command (the find one) returns failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49042/how-do-i-make-find-fail-if-exec-fails. I'm citing the two most likely useful ways of how to achieve your goal.

The easiest way is to use `xargs`, however this works only if you have no space in any path the `find` command can find:

```
find … -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 invalid_command
```

You can also get rid of find and use recursive globbing, or implement a recursive search on your own (I doubt your directory tree is deep enough to cause an issue) if you are stuck with an older Bash (bellow 4.x.x).

```
shopt -s globstar
set -e
for x in **/*.xml; do invalid_command "$x"; done
```

Also, if you don't need it to be a one-liner, you can at first find all the directories, save them e.g. to a tempfile (use `mktemp` for that), and then do anything you need with the list. Filter it further, run commands on them...

Comment: Collect 50 rep and convert it to a comment! Now I am too drunken to do it for you! But I love you!

Comment: Edited so it is not a link-only answer.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't have any space in my directories names. I will try the `xargs`. It's true that I trying to make a one-line command but maybe it's more easy to make multiple ones...

Comment: `find -print0 | xargs -0` should deal with whitespace in names just fine, provided of course that whatever `xargs` runs handles them properly. Also, it's probably worth noting, that the `xargs` solution will process all files, even if one of them fails. (`xargs` returns 123 if a command returns 1 to 125.) On the other hand, the loop here will abort immediately on a failure (because of the `set -e`), you'd need to make some flag variable to remember the error but to continue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if the last command exited with an error and then issue an `exit` command by appending `if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then exit ; fi` to the line.

Please note though that if the provided code snippit is part of a bigger script this will exit the script completely. You may want to consider rewriting it into a `for` or `while` loop so that you can use `break` instead.

Comment: Well `exit` doesn't really do anything with `find`, it doesn't even mind what the exit code is.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a `find`-only answer.  I don't think you can do this with only the POSIX features of `find`, but since you're already using some GNUisms, you can take advantage of the `-quit` primitive:

```
$ find -exec command {} \; -o -quit
```

This makes `find` quit immediately as soon as `command` fails (i.e. returns a non-zero exit code).  Now, to force `find` to also exit with a non-zero status, you need to get it to do something that will fail before the `-quit`.  One way to do this is

```
$ find -exec command {} \; -o -fprint /dev/full -quit
```

since all writes to `/dev/full` will fail.  You will get an error message like

```
find: ‘/dev/full’: No space left on device
```

which you can filter out with `2>/dev/null` if you want.

If you were using [NetBSD find](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?find+1+NetBSD-current), you could do this instead:

```
$ find -exec command {} \; -o -exit 1
```